# Cross Datacenter Replication Path in Cassandra Timeout

Tags: cassandra

Consider 2 data-centers in different geographical locations, correct me if any statement I have made is incorrect.

DC1's coordinator receives a write request from a client which it forwards to its local nodes containing the replicas. For a successful write to happen (Local_Quorum consistency level), the local nodes should have acknowledged the write to the coordinator within the Write_request_timeout_in_ms = 5000 ms period.

when DC1's coordinator receives the write request, it also sends the write request to a coordinator in DC2, which passes on the request to the local nodes containing the replica data. These DC2 nodes are not required to acknowledge back within the 5000 ms for the write mutation to be a success, only DC1 nodes need to respond within that 5000 ms for a successful write.

So my question is what timers govern the write requests happening at DC2? The DC2 coordinator has to respond back to the DC1 coordinator within a specific timeout period, otherwise DC1 coordinator stores a hinted handoff for DC2, so what is that specific timeout period called in the cassandra.yaml file?